# VM detection mechanisms for ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, virtual-machine, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I'm currently developing a cross-platform VM detection library (for anti-cheat, not malware just to clarify) and I'm planning on adding cross-architecture support as well, specifically for ARM CPUs.

I'm familiar with x86 and have experience with this ISA, but ARM's ISA is pretty much an alien world to me. I've tried searching for any ARM VM detection techniques but to no avail.

Are there any mechanisms that already exist? Or would I need to dig deep in the ARM developer manual for days, hoping to discover some sort of hacky trick?

Comment: It sounds like there is no fully reliable way to detect a virtual environment, irrespective of architecture. See: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361318/knowing-if-we-are-running-in-a-vm-programmatically#comment131280476_74361318) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911300/c-convenient-way-to-check-if-system-is-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: Bing chat returned this but I've not verified its validity: The ID_AA64MMFR0_EL1 system register can be used to check for the presence of a hypervisor on ARMv8-A and later processors. This register is part of the ARMv8-A architecture and provides information about the memory management features of the processor. The Hypervisor feature is one of the features that can be detected using this register.